# GIT diff external visual program and output text diff

Tags: git

Is it possible to config GIT so that it will output to a visual diff program (i.e. Meld) and also dump the text out like when running GIT without a visual diff program installed.

For meld I'm doing something similar: https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-meld-for-git-diffs-in-ubuntu-hardy

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
os.system('meld "%s" "%s"' % (sys.argv[2], sys.argv[5]))
```

One thing I tried was to change the python script to first call Meld and then call GIT with –no-ext-diff and redirect it's output to standard out.  Since I didn't want to wait for Meld to finish I replaced the blocking os.system with non-blocking subprocess.Popen.  The problem with this is that git removes the tmp file generated from the repo before Meld can read it.

I was hoping there was a way to configure .gitconfig so that it will send to both the diff program and still send the diff text at the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this feature exists. The closest I believe you can get is to create an alias in your bash (Linux or MacOSX) that executes something like this:

```
git difftool -y & git diff
```

This way it will open the external diff tool and print the diff in the console.